# Can't open HDF5 file bigger than memory... ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bigdata, hdf5, vaex

I have many .csv of NYC taxi from [nyc.gov](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page), one .csv = year-month. There I grab cca 15 of csvs and make HDF5s from them:

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import os 
import glob
import numpy as np

import vaex
from tqdm import  tqdm_notebook as tqdm

#hdf = pd.HDFStore('c:/Projekty/H5Edu/NYCTaxi/NYCTaxi.hp')
#df1 = pd.read_csv('path nejake csvcko')
#hdf.put('DF1', df1, format = 'table', data_columns = True)


csv_list = np.sort(np.array(glob.glob('G:\\NYCTaxi\\*.csv')))[::-1]

csv_list = csv_list[20:39]

output_dir = 'c:\\Datasety\\YelowTaxi\\DataH5\\'

for file in tqdm(csv_list, leave=False, desc='Converting to hdf5...'):
    # Setting up the files, and directories
    #zip_file = ZipFile(file)
    output_file = file.split('\\')[-1][:-3]+'hdf5'
    output = output_dir + output_file
    #output = output_file
    
    # Check if a converted file already exists: if it does skip it, otherwise read in the raw csv and convert it
    if (os.path.exists(output) and os.path.isfile(output)):
        pass
    else:
        # Importing the data into pandas 
        #pandas_df = [pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0)][0]
        pandas_df = [pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0, low_memory=False)][0]
        # Rename some columns to match the more well known dataset from 
        # http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html
        

        # Importing the data from pandas to vaex
        vaex_df = vaex.from_pandas(pandas_df, copy_index=False)
        
        # Export the data with vaex to hdf5
        vaex_df.export_hdf5(path=output, progress=False)
```

Next I make one big HDF5:

```
import re
import glob
import vaex
import numpy as np

def tryint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s

def alphanum_key(s):
    """ Turn a string into a list of string and number chunks.
        "z23a" -> ["z", 23, "a"]
    """
    return [ tryint(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', s) ]

hdf5_list = glob.glob('c:\\Datasety\\YelowTaxi\\DataH5\\*.hdf5')
hdf5_list.sort(key=alphanum_key)
hdf5_list = np.array(hdf5_list)

#assert len(hdf5_list) == 3, "Incorrect number of files"

# This is an important step
master_df = vaex.open_many(hdf5_list)

# exporting
#master_df.export_hdf5(path='c:\\Datasety\\YelowTaxi\\DataH5\\Spojene.hd5', progress=True)
master_df.export_hdf5(path='c:\\Datasety\\YelowTaxi\\DataH5\\Spojene.hdf5', progress=True)
```

So far, everything is ok, I can open output file Spojene.hdf5.

Next, I append new .csv to Spojene.hdf5:

```
for file in csv_list:
#file = csv_list[0]
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0, low_memory=False)
    filename = 'c:\\Datasety\\YelowTaxi\\DataH5\\Spojene.hdf5'
    df2.to_hdf(filename, 'data', append=True)
```

But, when I append new .csv to Spojene.hdf5, I cant open it:

```
df = vaex.open('c:\\Datasety\\YelowTaxi\\DataH5\\Spojene.hdf5')
```

ValueError: First columns has length 289184484, while column table has length 60107988

[image: Error message]

Pls, what can I do?

Comment: File size shouldn't be a problem. It is common to open HDF5 files that are larger than RAM (at least with h5py, PyTables, C, C++ and FORTRAN). That's the whole point of HDF5. Check your 2nd process - it's different from the 1st. When you create `Spojene.hdf5`, you load data with `pd.read_csv()`, then convert to vaex with `.from_pandas()` then `.export_hdf5()`. The 2nd time, you load with `pd.read_csv()`, but add the data to `Spojene.hdf5` directly with `df2.to_hdf()`. Different processes -- different results? Investigate the data schema for each process. Maybe they aren't consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is linked to how pandas is creating hdf5 files. According to vaex's [documentation](https://vaex.io/docs/faq.html#Why-can%27t-I-open-a-HDF5-file-that-was-exported-from-a-pandas-DataFrame-using-.to_hdf?) you can't open a HDF5 file with vaex if it has been created via `to_hdf` pandas method. I assume it is the same if you append to an existing HDF5 file.

To avoid this error you can reuse your logic where you convert the pandas dataframe to a vaex dataframe, export it to HDF5 and then use `open_many`. Something like this should work:

```py
main_hdf5_file_path = "c:\\Datasety\\YelowTaxi\\DataH5\\Spojene.hdf5"

hdf5_files_created = []
for file in csv_list:
   hdf5_file = file.replace(".csv", ".hdf5")
   # from_csv can take additional parameters to forward to pd.read_csv
   # You can also use convert=True to convert it automatically to hdf5 without the export_hdf5
   # Refer to https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/docs/api.html#vaex.from_csv
   df = vaex.from_csv(file) 
   df.export_hdf5(hdf5_file)
   hdf5_files_created.append(hdf5_file)

hdf5_to_read = hdf5_files_created + [main_hdf5_file_path]

final_df = vaex.open_many(hdf5_to_read)
final_df.export_hdf5(main_hdf5_file_path)
```